# Highcharts JSON graph not showing in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, canvas, highcharts

I'm currently using the Highcharts package to dynamically create graphs using the Highcharts package. Everything was going swimmingly until I decided to test on the web developers best friend, IE. Surprise, surprise, it doesn't like my code. My code can be seen below, along with a sample of my data, to give you an idea of what I'm working with:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Preprocessing Test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <link href="chemistry.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {

    var options = {
        chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
        zoomType: 'x',
    },
            plotOptions: {
                spline: {
                    lineWidth: 3,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 1
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5',
                        borderColor: 'black',
                        borderRadius: 10,
                        borderWidth: 3
                        },
                         marker: {
                             enabled: false,
                             states: {
                                  hover: {
                                     enabled: true,
                                     symbol: 'circle',
                                      radius: 2,
                                     lineWidth: 1,

                                 }
                             }
                         }
                    }
             },
         title: {
              text: 'Preprocessed Example'
         },
         xAxis: {   
                 categories: [],
                 labels: {
                        step: 1
                 },
                 turboThreshold: 2000,
                 title: {
                 text: 'Test'
                         }

         },
         yAxis: {
             title: {
                 text: 'Test'
              }
         },
         series: [{
             data:[],
             name: 'Test'
         }]
     };
          $.getJSON('files/nmr/Trimethylbenzene_test.json', function(data) {
            options.series[0].data = data;
             var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });

     });
          </script>
     </head>
     <body>

         <div style="height: 400px;min-width:300px;" id="container"></div>

     </body>
     </html>
```

and then an example of a few lines of my JSON file:

```
[
   [-4.16606,-2.535],
   [-4.16574,-1.787],
   [-4.16543,0.465],
   [-4.16511,1.98],
   [-4.1648,1.303],
   [-4.16449,-0.787],
   [-4.16417,-1.571],
   [-4.16386,-1.797],
   [-4.16354,-2.251],
   [-4.16323,-1.614],
   [16.40641,-7.857]
 ]
```

Any idea why it's not working in IE?

Comment: it would help if you told us what actual error or symptoms you're getting ("doesn't like my code" is a little uninformative). Also, please tell us which IE version(s) you're testing with (it's very often the most relevant piece of information in an IE question, so I don't get why so many people don't think to mention it :-) ).

Comment: Sorry, the entire graph fails to load, it just does nothing. No axis, no data, it's almost as if it's ignoring the fact it's meant to be putting the data somewhere. I've tested on IE 6, 7 and 8, and it's failed to work on all 3 of them, yet works absolutely fine on various versions of Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that IE is choking on the trailing commas at the end of your javascript objects:

```
                    marker: {
                         enabled: false,
                         states: {
                              hover: {
                                 enabled: true,
                                 symbol: 'circle',
                                  radius: 2,
                                 lineWidth: 1, <-- IE doesn't like that comma!
                             }
                         }
                     }
```

Remove it and the other ones like it.

Comment: great answer my friend :) :)